# Add Small and Base Image on same page Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How do I add Small and Base image on the same page in Magento?

I want to call both images on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image') ?>" alt="" />
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')" alt="" />
```

**[EDIT]**
You cannot see the `image` attribute in the product listing because the attribute does not have `Use in product listing` set to `yes`. And for some reason Magento does not allow you to set this directly from the attribute edit page for `Media Gallery` attributes. But you can set it manually in the database. First you need to get the `id` if the `image` attribute. This query should do the trick.

```
SELECT e.* FROM `eav_attribute` e LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et on e.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id WHERE e.attribute_code = 'image' and et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
```

After getting the `id` (for me it's 85) run this query to set it to be used in product listing.

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET `used_in_product_listing` = 1 WHERE `attribute_id` = 85
```

Replace `85` with your attribute id. Clear the cache and reindex everything. This worked for me.

Comment: 'image' is calling a default magento image. I want the Base image to be displayed when you mouse over here http://shop.lopezi.com/

Comment: @lopezi You should have mentioned that you need this for the product list page. See my update to the answer.